# Python Wand output file size before filesave

Tags: python, python-3.x, wand

I'm building an application that uses wand to resize and generate thumbnails for photos in the system. I want to generate moving gif thumbnails, which works in the code below. However I don't want to get giant thumbnail file sizes. In the case where the thumbnail would exceed say `5mb`, I want it to generate a `jpeg` thumbnail instead.

```
from wand.image import Image

with Image(filename="initial.gif") as img:
    size = img.width if img.width < img.height else img.height
    img.crop(width=size, height=size, gravity='center')
    img.resize(256, 256)
    img.format = 'gif'
    img.save(filename="output.gif")
```

Is there a way with `wand` to check the output file size before saving the file?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [make_blob()](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.4.4/wand/image.html#wand.image.Image.make_blob)

and then use len() to count the number of bytes